# Is it possible to eliminate do loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90

As we know, more recent versions of Fortran support array operations, which can eliminate many loops. So I was wondering if it would be possible to eliminate even the last remaining loop in following code snippet (as to make it a one-liner):

```
subroutine test(n,x,lambda)
   integer, intent(in) :: n
   real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x
   real, dimension(:), intent(out) :: lambda
   real :: eps
   integer :: i

   do i=1,n
      lambda(i) = product(x(i)-x, mask=(abs(x(i)-x) > epsilon(eps)))
   enddo
end subroutine
```

Its intention is to calculate `n` `lambda(i)` values in which

```
lambda(i) = (x(i)-x(1))*(x(i)-x(2))*...*(x(i)-x(i-1)*(x(i)-x(i+1))*...*(x(i)-x(n))
```

Comment: Loops are often slow in interpreted languages like Matlab and Python, but Fortran compilers have been optimizing loops for more than 50 years. If a loop is the most straightforward way to implement an algorithm, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with an implied do-loop in the array creation? something like `real, dimension(:), intent(out):: lambda =(/product(x(i)-x, mask=(abs(x(i)-x)>epsilon(eps))), i=1, n/)` ... I am not sure about the syntax here, but something like that might work.
You might even be able to create the array without calling the subroutine and do it in your main program, if your `x`-array is available.

Hope it helps.

Comment: did this work? I haven't tried it myself. It was more thought to be a hint in that direction.

Comment: It won't work at a syntax level: it's missing `()` around the implied do and it attempts to initialize a dummy argument (with something not allowed in initialization).  Those are quite fixable, though.

Answer (score 2):

OK, try this

```
lambda = product(max(spread(x, dim=1, ncopies=size(x)) - &
            spread(x, dim=2, ncopies=size(x)), eps), dim=2)
```

That's a one-liner.  It's also rather wasteful of memory and much less comprehensible than the original.

Comment: Nice one ;-) I was also on the track of `spread`, but the combination with `max` instead of a mask... beautiful!

Comment: This answer is also wrong, as it will include terms equal to `eps` in the multiplications where OP's original had no terms at all.  But then, elegance always trumps correctness !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can shorten this, `product` can use 2D arrays:

1. You would first need to set up a matrix of the differences:

```
   do i=1,n
     mat(:,i) = x(i) - x
   enddo
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
   forall ( i=1:n ) mat(:,i) = x(i) - x
```

2. Now you can do the product along the second dimension:

```
   lambda = product(mat, dim=2, mask=(abs(mat) > epsilon(eps)))
```

Whole program:

```
program test
   integer, parameter  :: n = 3
   real, dimension(n) :: x
   real, dimension(n) :: lambda
   real, dimension(n,n) :: mat
   real :: eps = 1.
   integer :: i

   call random_number( x )

   do i=1,n
      lambda(i) = product(x(i)-x, mask=(abs(x(i)-x) > epsilon(eps)))
   enddo
   print *,lambda

   forall ( i=1:n ) mat(:,i) = x(i) - x
   lambda = product(mat, dim=2, mask=(abs(mat) > epsilon(eps)))
   print *,lambda

end program
```

Comment: It's not really a one-liner.